# How to add an element within the <ul> list

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap typeahead.js to display a drop down list. I have this:

```
<ul class="abc">
        <li class="data-list"></li>
        <li class="data-list"></li>
        <li class="data-list"></li>
        <li class="data-list"></li>
        <li class="data-list"></li>
    </ul>
```

And I want to add an element

within the  list something like this:

```
<ul class="abc">
        <p>This is a list page</p>
        <li class="data-list"></li>
        <li class="data-list"></li>
        <li class="data-list"></li>
        <li class="data-list"></li>
        <li class="data-list"></li>
    </ul>
```

Below is the screenshot attached on where iim trying to add the element.

[image]

The element should be above the first `<li>` i.e 'Testing'.
Any ideas please?? Thanks!

Comment: You're just looking for the jquery necessary to prepend an p into the ul? You realize that's invalid markup, right?

Comment: I don't think adding `p` to a `ul` as a child is a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you decide to use jQuery, you could use [prepend()](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
$(".abc").prepend("<p>This is a list page</p>");
```

Though if you have multiple lists or multiple elements with that class, I might assign that particular list a unique id and use that to prepend something onto the element.

Of course if you wanted to add a `<li>` element which would be correct HTML, it would something similar.

```
$(".abc").prepend("<li>This is a list page</li>");
```

As per Alejandro's suggestion: If you wanted to use the paragraph element for custom style, you could add a class to the prepended list element and modify the CSS from there.

```
$('.abc').prepend( $('<li>This is a list page</li>').addClass('data-text') );
```

You would then be able to add style to `li.data-text` without using paragraphs improperly in your list.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(".abc").prepend("<li>Something</li>");` ? I don't know if prepending a paragraph will be correct for HTML.

Comment: Sure, if the OP wanted a list element. In the example given, it's a `<p>` element.

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness... I would use `$('.abc').prepend( $('<li>Something</li>').addClass('data-text') );` and then customize the CSS for `li.data-text` elements, avoiding using **paragraphs**.